# What font can give me the Christmas tree?

Tags: fonts, symbols, fontspec, unicode

I succeed in obtaining e.g. ☦︎, from Unicode U+2626, by means of the Arial Unicode MS font. But it does not give me the evergreen tree, or Christmas tree with unicode U+1F332. What fonts may I use to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This requires a current lualatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\notoemoji{Noto Color Emoji}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]

\begin{document}

{\notoemoji ^^^^^^01f332}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I run `albatross 0x1F332` (a new tool in texlive) I get the following fonts as alternatives:

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Font name                                                                   │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ EmojiOne Color                                                              │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Noto Color Emoji                                                            │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Noto Emoji                                                                  │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ OpenMoji                                                                    │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Quivira                                                                     │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Segoe UI Emoji                                                              │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Segoe UI Symbol                                                             │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Symbola                                                                     │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Twemoji Mozilla                                                             │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: From the first I get the error message LaTeX3 Error: Command '\notoemoji' already defined!For immediate help type H <return>. ...toemoji{Noto Color Emoji}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]

Comment: certainly not from my example. But if your document already defines the notoemoji font, then choose another name.

Comment: Very beautiful the choose of the symbol. Appreciated it much.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

\faTree
 
\end{document}
```

[image: faTree]

Source: [*The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), pag. 196.